# Java Index for an asked number using Array and while loop

Tags: java, arraylist

How do i find the index here? Am i missing something?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        int red = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());
        if (red == -1) {
            break;
        }

        list.add(red);
    }

    System.out.println("");

    // toteuta tänne toiminnallisuus luvun etsimiseen
    int num = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (index <= list.size()) {

        num = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());
        System.out.println("What are we looking for? " + num);

        i = list.get(index);

        break;

    }
    i++;
    index++;

    System.out.println("number " + num + " is in index " + i);
}

}
```

With:
51
22
-11
-140
-18
-1
22

Print is:

> What are we looking for?
>
> 22 number 22 is in index 52

Comment: `List.get(int index)` returns the element at the given index. Not the other way around. We cannot give an element value and get the index.

Answer (score 2):

If your are trying to find the index of a value in the ArrayList then you should use the `indexOf` method. Using `get` will return the element at that index.

So your code would look like this:

```
while (index <= list.size()) {

    num = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());
    System.out.println("What are we looking for? " + num);

    // changes here
    i = list.indexOf(num);
    break;

}
i++;
```

Note: not sure why you are incrementing the result by 1 before returning it, I guess you want to find the index starting from 1 instead of 0? If that is the case than it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find "num" value in list then take look at below code.

```
    num = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());
    System.out.println("What are we looking for? " + num);

    while (index <= list.size()) {
        if(list.get(index)==num){
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println("number " + num + " is in index " + index);
```